# FSC - Adding a column to "Investment accounts" related list under person account

Tags: page-layout, related-list, person-accounts, financial-services-cloud

I need to add a new column/field to the "Investment account" related list but do not see it in either the Account or Person Account page layout - is this controlled elsewhere in FSC?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is controlled via Field Sets.

Setup -> Object Manager -> Financial Account -> Field Sets -> Choose field set( WM_Client_InvestmentAccount OR WM_Household_InvestmentAccount) -> Add Field -> Save